# Powershell configuration file

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-terminal

So I have this PowerShell configuration file, git branches are showing just fine, the problem is when I'm in every folder location is shows `PS` at the end:

[image: powershell]

Here's my script (I don't really know if I'm missing something here, maybe with the `else` path):

```
function prompt {
  $p = Split-Path -leaf -path (Get-Location)
  $user = $env:UserName
  $host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "\" + $p + ">"
  $host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = "Blue"

  if (Test-Path .git) {
    $p = Split-Path -leaf -path (Get-Location)
    git branch | ForEach-Object {
      if ($_ -match "^\*(.*)") {
        $branch = $matches[1] + " - "
        Write-Host -NoNewLine $user -ForegroundColor Magenta
        Write-Host -NoNewLine "@\"
        Write-Host -NoNewLine $p -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Write-Host -NoNewLine " - " -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
        Write-Host -NoNewLine $branch -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    Write-Host -NoNewLine $user -ForegroundColor Magenta
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "@\"
    Write-Host -NoNewLine $p -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Write-Host -NoNewLine " "
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Because your custom `prompt` function produces no (non-empty) *success-stream* output** (see [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection)), **PowerShell infers that you haven't defined this function at all, and prints its *default* prompt string, `PS>`** (in your case *after* what the `Write-Host` calls printed).

- This requirement is also explained in the conceptual [about_Prompts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Prompts) topic.

**To avoid this problem, send at least a *one*-character string to the success output stream** (rather than using [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host), which by default prints straight to the *host*).

E.g. (see the penultimate line):

```
function prompt {
  $p = Split-Path -leaf -path (Get-Location)
  $user = $env:UserName
  $host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "\" + $p + ">"
  $host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = "Blue"

  if (Test-Path .git) {
    $p = Split-Path -leaf -path (Get-Location)
    git branch | ForEach-Object {
      if ($_ -match "^\*(.*)") {
        $branch = $matches[1] + " - "
        Write-Host -NoNewLine $user -ForegroundColor Magenta
        Write-Host -NoNewLine "@\"
        Write-Host -NoNewLine $p -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Write-Host -NoNewLine " - " -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
        Write-Host -NoNewLine $branch -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    Write-Host -NoNewLine $user -ForegroundColor Magenta
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "@\"
    Write-Host -NoNewLine $p -ForegroundColor Yellow
  }
  '> ' # !! Output to the success output stream to prevent default prompt.
}
```

Comment: Ohhh, completely forgot about the default value, thanks so much for the explanation!

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @crisleo94; my pleasure. Frankly, PowerShell should base its behavior on the _presence_ of a `prompt` function instead.